How do I keep French bread loaves from drying out while in the Couche?
When rising my french bread loaves or baguettes: how do I keep them moist enough to expand without making a mess of the couche?
Ciabattas for instance have short proofing times as they still have their air. But FB starts with the air knocked out takes a couple of hours to rise. Can I put the couche in a proof box?

There are different methods, I use a very large clear plastic bag. First I slide the dough into it, then I spray a mist of water before blowing into it to inflate it. Lastly I pinch it closed and crimp it down with a bag clip. Because it's clear I can watch progress, and inflating it keeps the bag from coming in contact with and sticking to the dough. This method works with any of my longer proofs.
The only slightly tricky part is getting the bread out without the bag collapsing and sticking, I just get my arm in the opening quickly and hold it up while sliding the bread out with the other.
Another method you could use if you are making this type of bread often is to cut off part of a cardboard box and tape clear plastic film over the top to make a kind of proof box. All you would have to do is place it over the bread. The only downside is you'd have to store it somewhere between uses, while a plastic bag takes up almost no space.

Thank you. goof ideas
